# How to break out of a loop by writing the same word 3 times in a row (word+return key ,3 times)?

Tags: ruby

I have to break out of a loop by typing the same word "BYE" 3 times in a row and i'm out of ideas, this is how i tried but its not working:

the test:

```
  elsif var == 'BYE' * 3
          break
```

the original code:

```
while true
    timeVar = rand(1930..1950)
    inputVar = gets.chomp
    if inputVar == inputVar.downcase
        puts ' HUH?! SPEAK UP SONNY!!! '
    elsif inputVar  == inputVar.upcase && inputVar != 'BYE'
        puts 'NO, NOT SINCE ' + timeVar.to_s + ' !'
    elsif inputVar == 'BYE'
        break
    end
end
```

and the working solution implemented :

```
bye_count = 0
while bye_count < 3 do 
    time_grandma = rand(1930..1950)
    input_var = gets.chomp
    if input_var == "BYE" then
        bye_count += 1
    else
        bye_count = 0
    end
    if input_var == input_var.downcase
        puts ' HUH?!? SPEAK UP SONNY!!'
    elsif input_var == input_var.upcase
        puts ' NO, NOT SINCE ' + time_grandma.to_s + ' !'
    end
end
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Can you provide the rest of the code for this loop?

Comment: ok sry, im new at this

Comment: @Horned do you want the program to quit when you put in "BYEBYEBYE" or do you want it to quit when you put in "BYE" + return key, three times?

Comment: You mean if 'bye' is entered 3 times ('bye' + enter 3 times) or you mean if 'bye bye bye' is entered once ?

Comment: BYE + return key, three times in a row

Comment: Variable names should be written in `snake_case`. And you shouldn't mark a variable as such (via a `var` suffix). What if you decide to extract the variable into a method later on? Better use a descriptive name like `random_year`.

Comment: thanks for the tip Stefan, will do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adjust your code to look something like this.

```
bye_count = 0
while bye_count < 3 do
  input_var = gets.chomp
  # ...
  if input_var == "BYE" then
    bye_count += 1
  else
    bye_count = 0
  end
end
```

Comment: I think this needs an else byte_count=0  to cater for the fact then it should be BYE 3 times in a row  and not 3 times overall (?)

Comment: @HeikoRupp Thank you. I've made the change.

Comment: @Horned Is the topmost arrow orange? You may have clicked down by mistake. Thank you for accepting, anyway.

Comment: yes, i've clicked the topmost arrow, i was surprised too when i saw -1

Comment: Try clicking it again. It might undo something.

Comment: i get the message " thanks for the feedback! votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score" , so that means it wasnt me ?, anyway thanks again for help !!

Comment: @JörgWMittag I did make a small mistake in the first version, but I have corrected that. Have you found another problem?

Comment: There is no such thing as `bye_count++` in Ruby

Comment: Ruby has no `++` unary operator, and have no postfix unary operator at all, so I edit your answer to be valid.

Comment: @steenslag and MikDiet Thank you. I've been using so many different languages recently that I keep forgetting which ones have what.

Comment: It would be prudent to run your code before posting in future.